# XSL doesn't show HTML tables

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML file containing information on hotels which I try to display using XSL, but the data doesn't show on the web page (I have no HTML tables). I read a lot of posts on StackOverflow, but I still can't see where my mistake could be.

**An excerpt of my XML file:**

```
<entries xmlns="http://ref.otcnice.com/webservice/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:SchemaLocation="http://ref.otcnice.com/webservice/entries.xsd">

 <entry>
   <ID>1021</ID>
   <name_fr>AC BY MARRIOTT NICE</name_fr>
   <name_fr_short>AC BY MARRIOTT NICE</name_fr_short>
   <address>
      <address_line1>59 Promenade des Anglais</address_line1>
      <address_line2/>
      <address_line3/>
      <zip>06000</zip>
      <city>NICE</city>
   </address>
   <phone>+33 (0)4 93 97 90 90</phone>
 </entry>
<!--.........-->
</entries>
```

**Part of my XSL code:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th width='380'>Adresse</th>
        <th width='175'>Téléphone</th>
        <th>Site Web</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="entries/entry">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">/ProjetMiage/detail /?id=<xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="target">detail
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="name_fr"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="website"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="target">
                    blank
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="website"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like you have not declared a prefix for the namespace used by the `entries` element in the source XML, so that the reference `entries/entry` selects nothing. Seeing both documents in full would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is almost certainly because of namespaces. In your XML, the first line is as follows:

```
<entries xmlns="http://ref.otcnice.com/webservice/" ...
```

The `xmlns=` here is a namespace declaration. In particular, it is a declaration for the default namespace, meaning this element, and all descendant elements (unless overridden) belong to this namespace.

In your XSLT it is very possible you have not declared any namespace. This means when you do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="entries/entry">
```

It is looking for **entries** and **entry** elements that belong to NO namespace. These are different to elements which do belong to a namespace, even if the actual name of the element is the same.

If you were using XSLT 2.0, you could simply set the **xpath-default-namespace** property, like so

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xpath-default-namespace="http://ref.otcnice.com/webservice/">
```

Then, XSLT would assume any element referenced in an xpath expression, which didn't have an explicit namespace prefix, would belong to this namespace.

If you are using XSLT 1.0, you would have to declare your namespace along with a prefix

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:o="http://ref.otcnice.com/webservice/">
```

(The prefix "o" here can actually be any prefix you chose, by the way. It is the URI that has to match the XML).

Then, whenever you wanted to reference an element in this namespace, you would add the prefix to it, to indicate the namespace. For example

```
<xsl:for-each select="o:entries/o:entry">
    <xsl:value-of select="o:website"/>
```

As an aside, your XSLT is very verbose. Instead of writing this...

```
            <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="website"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="target">
                blank
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="website"/>
            </xsl:element>
```

You can instead write this (Note the use of curly braces `{ }` which indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally).

```
<a href="{website}" target="_blank">
   <xsl:value-of select="website" />
</a>
```

(Don't forget to do "o:website" if you were using XSLT 1.0")